# mongoose can't save data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I meet some trouble need your help ~~ thx

I am use mongoose + superAgent + feedparser + eventProxy to get Rss and save these datas

now I can get and finish parse these dataes however I can't save them with moogose

I have 3 module are dao.js , app.js and service.js

I configure dao as this codes

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"), 
    db, 
    modelName = "news"; // 设定操作的collections
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");

    db = mongoose.connection;


    db
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Connection Error!!! this's some prompts: ");
        console.log(err);
    })
      .once("open", function () {
        console.log("Open DataBase Successfully!!!");
    });

// 设置
var newsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        "category": String,
        "data": [{
            "title": String,
            "link": String,
            "pubDate": String,
            "source": String,
            "author": String    
        }]    
    });


    console.log(newsSchema.ObjectId);

newsSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if( !this.title ) {
        this.title = "未知标题";
    }

    next();
})

var newsModel = mongoose.model(modelName, newsSchema);

module.exports = {
    model: newsModel,
    schema: newsSchema,
    mongoose,
    db
}
```

and save data as these codes:

```
saveData(callback) {
    var $self = this;
    for(var i = 0; i<$self.result.length; i++) {
         new model($self.result[i]).save(function (err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("数据存储成功!")
            }
        });
    }
    callback && callback();    
    db.close();
}
```

Now the data can't save successfully meanwhile the save callback func don't run

Could you give me some advise?

Comment: $self.result is data array , these are all legal

Comment: `db.close()` is called before any of the `.save()` calls are processed.

Comment: problem was solved!!  Thx you